# Is there a way to skip or satisfy a scenario based on a boolean?

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a situation where feature-toggling is implemented in an application and I want to have automated Selenium tests that are in place for both states of the application. (Both states are possible in a production state.) The tests that are executed would be based on the feature-toggling configuration that is present in the web application.

In a normal situation, using "Scenario Outline" will result in a generated test that can be executed via Test Explorer, and the CI process for an application can be configured to execute all of the tests that are part of the test assembly after it is built. In my situation, an application state could cause one test to pass and another test to fail (think lack of UI controls because of a feature state). I looked into hooks and I see that there is a BeforeScenario tag, but I don't think this gets me what I'm wanting to achieve so much as it allows me to do some setup before a scenario executes.

Comment: Wouldn't the feature toggle merely be a condition of the test, like any other condition?

Comment: If you imagine a feature that could be in both states in production because of a canary rollout system, then the feature toggle couldn't be a condition, could it? A single toggle would be something that would be assumed for the test. Using SpecFlow, you can't write conditional paths using Given/When/Then. For unit tests, you can easily write two tests and test the expected paths based on the toggle state. The conundrum here is that I'm wanting to have automated tests in Selenium, and Selenium acts against a single state of the application, not an arranged state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually include a step that sets the scenario to "pending".

```
Scenario: Some new feature
    Given pending story 123
    Given condition
    When action that includes new feature
    Then something
```

The step definition for `Given pending story 123` would call:

```
Assert.Inconclusive($"Pending story {storyNumber} (https://dev.azure.com/company/project/workitems/edit/{storyNumber})");
```

This marks the test inconclusive when using MS Test. We use Jenkins for continuous integration, and our builds continue passing. It's also handy because I can provide a link to the story or feature in something like Azure DevOps, GitHub, Jira or their ilk.

This is not exactly a feature toggle, but it is easy to remove or comment out the `Given pending` line of a scenario in your topic branch to enable the test.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're effectively putting in the "Given pending story 123" condition to make sure it doesn't fail on a branch where development hasn't occurred, right? I think that's slightly different than what I'm trying to achieve as I want my tests to be on the main branch since the intent is to test for a production release.

Comment: @RaymondMorris: These tests would be on the main branch. The "Given pending" lines just get removed on the branch where development is occurring. This should not be an issue for the main branch, since the tests are not technically failures. If you have a policy that "all tests must be passing" then people could view "inconclusive" tests as a problem. I would just explain to them what they mean: the test is pending development and is not actually running.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As I've ruminated on this, I believe it will work. On main, I don't want anything to fail because a feature has, as an example, replaced a button with two buttons and changed the flow. In fact, I don't want the test to fail on any branch. Inconclusive seems a sound choice for indicating that a test could not be performed because the condition required for the test was unavailable. I was tripped up by the "remove or comment out...in your topic branch" part of your answer. Instead of commenting, the different toggle states would dictate pass or fail.